# WCF+ duplex + Windows Form Application (ButtonClick) Trouble

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-forms-designer, duplex

I have WCF classes and now project to do. My teacher gave as to write app with streaming and duplex (I know that is impossible, but I found backdoor from this situation - I'm sending pics under 60KB).

My code worked well so far as I start wrote my GUI in Windows Form Application.

When I'm testing it via console - everything work well. But, when I want to use buttons in my GUI i have this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: This request operation sent to
>   net.tcp://localhost:7756/Przesylanie did not receive a reply within
>   the configured timeout (00:00:59.9740007).  The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be
>   because the service is still processing the operation or because the
>   service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider
>   increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to
>   IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure
>   that the service is able to connect to the client.

Here bunch of code:

Service + IService (due to limitation of Stack I put it to one file):

```
public void WyslijstrumienNaSerwer()
    {
        IPrzesylanieCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPrzesylanieCallback>();
        string sciezka = @"E:\5 semestr\Fras\Se płotek\Lab6\WcfServiceContractZadanie2\Host\bin\Pliki\" + "plik_odebrany.jpg";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.SystemDirectory, sciezka);
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        callback.WyslijStrumien(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine("meta");
    }

namespace WcfServiceContractZadanie2
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IPrzesylanieCallback))]
    public interface IPrzesylanie
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void WyslijstrumienNaSerwer();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPrzesylanieCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void WyslijStrumien(string filePath);
    }
}
```

Client + callback + form + References.cs:

```
namespace Aplikacja
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            PrzesylanieClient klient = new PrzesylanieClient(new InstanceContext(new PrzesylanieCallback()), "NetTcpBinding_IPrzesylanie");

            klient.WyslijstrumienNaSerwer();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
    }
    public class PrzesylanieCallback : Referencja1.IPrzesylanieCallback
    {
        public void WyslijStrumien(string filePath)
        {
            Form1 o1 = new Form1();

            //  Pobieranie obrazka od klienta
            string sciezka = @"E:\5 semestr\Fras\Se płotek\Lab6\WcfServiceContractZadanie2\Aplikacja\bin\Pliki\" + o1.wybrany();
            string filePathZrodla = Path.Combine(System.Environment.SystemDirectory, sciezka);

            //Otwieranie obrazka
            Stream strumien = null;
            try
            {
                FileStream imageFile = File.OpenRead(filePathZrodla);
                strumien = (Stream)imageFile;
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wyjatek otwierania pliku: {0}", ioe.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw ioe;
            }
            //  Zapisywanie obrazka
            o1.SaveFile(strumien, filePath);
        }
    }
}

 private void btnPrzeslijPlikNaSerwer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               PrzesylanieClient klient = new PrzesylanieClient(new InstanceContext(new PrzesylanieCallback()), "NetTcpBinding_IPrzesylanie");
            klient.WyslijstrumienNaSerwer();
        }

public void WyslijstrumienNaSerwer() {
       base.Channel.WyslijstrumienNaSerwer();
}
```

I wrote methods `SaveFile` which works correctly.

As you see, I'm testing my code in the begining of Main function in Client and that works well.

But when I'm using the same code in Forms it does not work. Compiler is returnig me to `References.cs` and gives me exception I mentioned earlier.

Waiting for any respone!

Comment: Links not working. I'm getting 404 - Page not found.

Comment: Just add the most relevant part of the stack trace.

Comment: You're using all local variables: `PrzesylanieClient klient` is a local variable inside your `Main` method. That means your client, your `InstanceContext`, your callback are all gone once the method exits. Also you allocate a `Form` inside your service callback class, which is... well, "unorthodox" to say the least. You need to learn how a `WinForm` application is structured.

Answer (score 0):

My answer does not solve your exception issue; however, it might prevent you from getting a very bad grade.  Streaming **AND** duplex are both supported in WCF.

Streaming:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Duplex:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I found information that I can use streming data only with single channel. But I bypassed it via using files under 60KB. My problem is appering wen I want to use klient side in windows form.

Comment: Was going to suggest this, but was unsure of how you are calling the service from your client:  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28265/WCF-Operation-Timeout-Exception)